# Devise token authentication - reset token per request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, token

I'm building a mobile app which authenticates through devises token authentication and can't decide how often the token should be reset.

I'm wondering if I reset and return a new token on every request (after initial login) would that have much of an impact on performance.

My user is updated on every request via the last_sign_in_at update, so adding a

```
before_save :reset_authentication_token
```

would create a new token which I could return in a header or by json per/request.

Are there many/any disadvantages to doing it this way?... maybe caching issues?